# The location of EmailLink command implementation

Tags: 2010, development, xml

My question is regarding a command which is bound to an OOTB button.
On the ribbon you have a button to email a link, so this buttons they have some commands like:
EmailLink, EmailLibraryLink, etc
For example you have following declaration of the email button:

```
      <Button
        Id="Ribbon.Library.Share.EmailLibraryLink"
        Sequence="10"
        Command="EmailLibraryLink"
        Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-16" Image16by16Left="-88"  
        Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-128" Image32by32Left="-448"
        LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButEmailLink;"
        ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButEmailLink;"
        ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButEmailLinkLibrary;"
        TemplateAlias="o1"                    
        />
```

So my question is, where exactly is this implemenation of the command? Where is the code that is beeing called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search the 14 hive for "EmailLink" or other OOB commands it finds the command in the file **SP.Ribbon.js** or **SP.Ribbon.debug.js**.  The debug version is the readable version.

This file is located in **\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.Ribbon.debug.js**